# Printing C linked list produces memory leak

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I am using Heapusage, an alternative to Valgrind. When I am printing my linked list in the main function, it produces memory leak (when the printing function is commented, it is all fine). I was trying to find out what is wrong, but the printing function is so simple, that either my heap analyzer is bugged or the problem is so simple, that I can't find it.

```
typedef struct Point {
  int x, y;
  struct Point *next;
} Point;

Point *NewPoint(const int x, const int y, Point *head) {
  Point *point = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point));
  point->next = NULL;
  point->x = x;
  point->y = y;
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = point;
  } else {
    Point *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = point;
  }
  return head;
}

void FreeList(Point *head) {
  Point *current = head;
  while (current != NULL) {
    Point *tmp = current;
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp);
  }
}

void PrintList(Point *head) {
  while (head) {
    printf("[%d, %d]\n", head->x, head->y);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  Point *head = NULL;
  head = NewPoint(2, 3, head);
  PrintList(head);
  FreeList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specifically does  your tool say is leaking, and on which line?

Comment: You have problems in your code. `head` needs to be passed by reference, i.e. `&head` and your function prototype needs to be `Point *NewPoint(const int x, const int y, Point **head)` and many changes to follow in this function to handle this essential change! Your current code can work fine if you change `head` to be global pointer and don't pass it as an argument to the funciton.

Comment: @hesham_EE C doesn't have pass by reference. And why does the function argument necessarily need to change from `*head` to `**head`?

Comment: @Miket25, I mean pass-by-poiner, sorry about my inaccurate usage of the term. He needs to change to `**head` as head already a pointer `Point *head` and he needs to change the value of this pointer in another function. So, he needs to pass a pointer to that pointer, hence `**head`.

Comment: Oh! I see now, he returns the new head. I thought he updates the head in the called function. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have no leaks, tested with valgrind-3.14.0.GIT

```
==13568== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13568== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13568== Using Valgrind-3.14.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13568== Command: ./a.out
==13568==  [2, 3]
==13568== 
==13568== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13568==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13568==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,040 bytes allocated
==13568== 
==13568== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13568== 
==13568== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13568== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I did the same and it doesn't report any errors with me either (valgrind-3.11.0)!

Comment: @DavidWichterle: Why not accept this answer, as this would close your question as being answered.